# increment value in mysql after the table has been created

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to change the value in the second column to increment and also change the current NULL values to start using that incrementing system that begins at a value other than 1. I do see I can use

```
ALTER TABLE t2 AUTO_INCREMENT = value;
```

to change the table to start incrementing at the number I want it to but the values them selves are still null how do I change my table from this:

```
| Id | OtherNumber | Name |
| -- |:-----------:| ----:|
| 1  | NULL        | Bob  |
| 2  | NULL        | Susan|
| 3  | NULL        | Bill |
```

to this

```
| Id | OtherNumber | Name |
| -- |:-----------:| ----:|
| 1  | 7           | Bob  |
| 2  | 8           | Susan|
| 3  | 9           | Bill |
```

How would I make the change if the table is in the hundreds of rows? Thanks

Comment: If you in any way care about the value of an auto-incremented column, DO NOT use AUTO_INCREMENT for that. Despite its name, the purpose of AUTO_INCREMENT is simply to ensure that values within that column are UNIQUE. It's convenient that they are (or may be) consecutive, but that point is largely irrelevant.

Comment: `update t2 set OtherNumber=id+6;`

Comment: now, you already have an auto_inc on `id` I take it. So I am clueless how OtherNumber is going to happen automatically. So I have taken the ball to the 40 yard line, and fumble

Comment: You can only have one auto-increment column in a table.

Comment: Which column is auto-increment -- `id` or `OtherNumber`?

Comment: how about if you leave Id as autoincrement, drop the OtherNumber column, and when you do a select, have OtherNumber be a derived column=Id+6, as it seems so important :>

Comment: I think @Drew idea will work well thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about if you leave `Id` as auto-increment, drop the `OtherNumber` column, and when you do a select, have `OtherNumber` be a derived column=Id+6

There, maybe some other Answers will come along. Others could be better.

Answer (score 2):

If you make "OtherNumber" the primary key when you alter it to auto increment, mysql should fill in the values for you

To change the starting number, it seems you need to use the old primary id column to get the "first" row in the table.  Mysql will then pick this value to start the auto increment from.

```
update t2 set OtherNumber = value where t2.Id = 1;
ALTER TABLE `test`.`new_table` 
CHANGE COLUMN `OtherNumber` `OtherNumber` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`OtherNumber`);
```

The nulls should be filled in with your auto increment setting.

You can later change the primary key back to the id column.